# Warnings and meta information in question

Tags: discussion, editing

Referring to this question: [How to enable root login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44418/how-to-enable-root-login) (and this [edit](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/44418/7) of that question).

There is an added remark in this question which doesn't seem to belong in the the body of a question:

> Mod Warning: Running as root is a bad idea - You never need to do it
>   but if you do you can very easily and irreparably destroy your system
>   and your data.

Apart from if you think this remark is needed, the placement and method are off as far as I'm concerned. It's meta-information, and should be ***at most*** a comment. It doesn't belong in the question body.

Also, it was removed by the origional poster, and then rolled back: looks like the beginning of a small edit party?

Overall I think that, just like "this is urgent" remarks, that remarks like "this is dangerous" do not belong edited in the question.

---

I wasn't sure if I needed to make this a meta-thing, but my flag was declined with this note:

> your flag comments are probably more appropriate on meta - suggest raise a question there with a link back to this Q.

So here we are:

Answer (score 1):

This was a rushed decision I was never happy with, but was out shouted about it a while ago. I think it serves to be [revisited again](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1409/au-policy-on-questions-about-root-login).

In my original answer when the question was raised, was to simply put a warning at the top of the **answer** to warn users of potential risks, not just for root but for any other potentially harmful things. Then I realized we do potentially harmful things whenever a user runs `sudo` and elevates their privileges. For me, I think it's *a lot* better if there is just a comment and at best a note in the answer about why you shouldn't run as root (with a link to the question why). No different then what we've been doing with users who say they are `chmod 0777` their web accessible directories.

I'd be interested to see what others think more than a year later.

Comment: I agree that in an answer a note might be/is valuable: you are giving extra information about the secrets you are trying to reveal :)